# Way to place multiple labels by creating one

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am making an app in which there are multiple labels which need to show up one after the other in a chain. Now, it would be really difficult if I had to create several labels with separate text on each one of them. So is there any way in which I can create one label, display it on the screen, then change the text of the same label by duplicating it, and display that just below the previous one?

Comment: UITableView / UICollectionView are probably good starting points

Comment: @luk2302 I can use these, but I don't know how many rows I need. They vary. Sometimes I might need 300 and sometimes just 200. Can I however create a variable called `rows` and increment it as and when I need more rows?

Comment: yes, you can certainly do that. There are ***tons*** of tutorials out there on how to use them.

Comment: @luk2302 I don't know why, but UITableView never struck me :/ Thanks!

Comment: @luk2302 Is there any way to change the text colour of one specific cell in a UITableView?

Comment: Yes, you have to overwrite the cellForRow... method and customize the label of one specific cell to have the desired font color.

Comment: @luk2302 Is there any way to assign one string to one cell, and then making each string fade in (animation) while all the others are hidden?

Comment: Yes, that is possible, but easier said than done - you can of course fade in the cells, but you have to write your own logic of how long some animations have to wait: e.g. the third cell has to wait 0.2 seconds if each cell animation takes 0.1 second (cell 1 and 2 have to complete first).

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion from luk2302 (in comments) is best way to achieve what you wanna do. But if you really-really wanna create multiple `label` bellow code will help.

You can use `for` loop to create several loop (as you either copy or create new it will take same amount of memory):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    print("%d",i)
    var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 21*i+5, 200,21))
    label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.text = "I'am a test label"
    self.view.addSubview(label)
}
```

Comment: Here the text of the new label created cannot be changed, right?

Comment: While creating it you can set it whatever text you wanna set.

Comment: Yes, but I want to change the text as `i` increases.

Comment: Yeah! Use an array for that.